# Whats the proper way to transmit updating data to a client via Django websockets?

Tags: reactjs, django, rest, websocket, django-rest-framework

Currently, I have an element that when clicked, sets up a global cooldown timer that effects all clients with the use of Django websockets. My issue is that while initially the websocket value is converted to `state` in my React client via `componentDidMount`, the websocket doesn't run again when its value changes in real time.

Heres how it works in detail.

The timer is updated via a django model, which I broadcast via my websocket to my React front-end with:

*consumer.py*

```
class TestConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("connected", event)
        await self.send({
            "type":"websocket.accept",
            
        })

        #correct way to grab the value btw, just work on outputting it so its streaming
        @database_sync_to_async
        def get_timer_val():
                val = Timer.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
                return val.time

        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": json.dumps({
                'timer':await get_timer_val(),
        })
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("received", event)
    
    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("disconnected", event)
```

This works initially, as my React client boots up and converts the value to `state`, with:

*component.jsx*

```
//handles connecting to the webclient
componentDidMount() {
    client.onopen = () => {
      console.log("WebSocket Client Connected");
    };
    client.onmessage = (message) => {
      const myObj = JSON.parse(message.data);
      console.log(myObj.timer);
      this.setState({ timestamp: myObj.timer });
    };
  }

//handles submitting the new timer upon clicking on element
handleTimer = () => {
    // handles making PUT request with updated cooldown timer upon submission,
    const timestamp = moment().add(30, "minutes");
    const curr_time = { time: timestamp };

    axios
      .put(URL, curr_time, {
        auth: {
          username: USR,
          password: PWD,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  };

//button that prompts the PUT request
<button
 type="submit"
 onClick={(e) => {
 this.handleTimer();
 //unrelated submit function
 this.handleSubmit(e);
 }}
>
Button
</button>
```

However, when a user clicks the rigged element and the database model changes, the web socket value doesn't until I refresh the page. I think the issue is that I'm only sending the websocket data during connection, but I don't know how to keep that "connection" open so any changes automatically get sent to the client server. I've looked through tons of links to find what the best way to implement real time is, but most of them are either about socket.io or implementing a chat app. All I want to do is stream a django models value to the front-end in real time.

Comment: Hi there. That's gonna be a little complicated =) Could you please attach the whole, properly formatted Consumer class, as well as the code that handles the model update on element click. If you already have a websocket connection working, it's already "kept" until the client disconnects, you only need a way to send data into this connection when the model is updated, we will try to figure that out after you post the code.

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov Thanks a ton for getting back to me, I amended the original post with as much relevant detail as I could provide. And your right, the client is on until it disconnects but I can't figure out how to send data in the meantime without refreshing. If you have any pointers I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I am here finally. Okay, so I really wanted to see the backed code that handles the `axios.put(URL, curr_time,` part, but I'll try to answer without it. Still, please add it if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to send updates triggered by some other code to the websocket connection, the `channels` part of `django-channels` comes into play. It works like this:

1. On connection, you add the websocket to some named group
2. When the value of Timer changes, you send the event (via the channels layer) with certain `type` to this group, from the code that triggered the changes.
3. Django-channels then invoke the method of the Consumer named after the type of the event for each websocket in the group
4. And finally, in this method, your code sends the message to the client

You need to configure then channels layer with the Redis. https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html

Now, step by step. I'll omit irrelevant parts.

1

```
async def websocket_connect(self, event):
    await self.send({
        "type":"websocket.accept"
    })
    await self.channel_layer.group_add('timer_observers', self.channel_name)
```

2 Here I am sending the event inside model, but you can do this in the view, or via django signals, however you want it. Also I am not checking whether the value actually changed, and I am assuming there is only one instance of Timer in the DB.

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

class Timer(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        async_to_sync(get_channel_layer().send)(
            'timer_observers', {"type": "timer.changed"}
        )
```

3+4
I have extracted the time-sending code to reuse it

```
class TestConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("connected", event)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept",
        })
        await self.channel_layer.group_add('timer_observers', self.channel_name)
        await self.send_current_timer()

    async def timer_changed(self, event):
        await self.send_current_timer()

    async def send_current_timer(self):
        @database_sync_to_async
        def get_timer_val():
            val = Timer.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
            return val.time
        
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": json.dumps({
                'timer': await get_timer_val(),
            })
        })
```

The idea here is that you handle internal events generated by your application the same way as external events from the client, i.e. `websocket.connect -> async def websocket_connect`. So the `channels` layer kinda "sends" you a "websocket message", and you respond (but to the actual client).

I hope that helps to understand the concepts. Probably what you are doing is overkill, but I assume that's just a learning exercise =)
I am not 100% sure this will work, so don't hesitate to ask additional questions.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation, with the steps along the way. It took me a few days just to implement this and its working. I appreciate the help Alexandr.

Comment: Whew, for a moment I thought you've dissapeared and will never read this =) Glad I was able to help.